# Configure sublime text 3 folder node_modules for node.js

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

I need node_modules in the sidebar but not when searching files, "go to files".

If I use

```
{
  "folder_exclude_patterns": [ "node_modules"]
}
```

It works ok except for the sidebar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need this setting `binary_file_pattern`:

```
    // These files will still show up in the side bar, but won't be included in
    // Goto Anything or Find in Files
    "binary_file_patterns": ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif", "*.ttf", "*.tga", "*.dds", "*.ico", "*.eot", "*.pdf", "*.swf", "*.jar", "*.zip"],
```

You can also use:

```
// index_exclude_patterns indicate which files won't be indexed.
"index_exclude_patterns": ["*.log"],
```

It's will show it in sidebar, but remove it from any index.

You can also try this plugin: https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarFolders

> For some users.. (me :P), the ST project system is too much.. I just
>   want to be able to switch folders without saving or tracking project
>   files, and keeping Tabs intact.. well, this package does just that.

Comment: tried both in different variations ("node_modules", "node_modules/*") using sublime3, Linux, build 3126: not working

Answer (score 43):

Sublime text -> Preferences -> Settings->  opens a new window with all the program settings on the left and your user settings on the right.   You would add this line between the {} brackets -

```
"binary_file_patterns": [".svn/", ".git/", "node_modules/", "bower_components/"]
```